# Derailleur tension pulley thread damaged by vibration?

Tags: repair, derailleur-rear

I have been riding my RD-5800 this week with a slightly misaligned hanger. It had some difficult shifting, but it was ridable.

So the hanger alignment tool arrived today, and I decided to clean the derailleur and re-grease the jockey wheels after aligning the hanger. To my incredible surprise, when trying to re-tighten the tension pulley screw, the aluminium forming the thread broke off from the inner plate. I have now a useless derailleur.

I am trying to establish the probable cause of the problem to prevent a similar scenario in the future. Firstly, I would like to precise that the bolt has never been subjected to more than 4 N.m (Shimano max = 5 N.m), so I don't think that is the problem.

Every 2-3 weeks, I remove the jockey wheels to re-grease the bushings. I have been doing that for the last 8 months.

Do you think that the frequent removal of the jockey wheels caused the problem, or it may be due to the vibration experienced by the misaligned hanger?

Follow-up: I have temporarily replaced the bolt with a M5 longer one and a nut on the other side. It is not the better solution, since it is threaded in the bushing portion, but it will last until my new derailleur arrives.

Comment: "Every 2-3 weeks, I remove the jockey wheels to re-grease the bushings. I have been doing that for the last 8 months." -- why? That's an insane frequency of doing that (probably well beyond the design amount).

Comment: I've never seen a derailer fail in the way you describe.  I suspect that you misthreaded the bolt when you were greasing the bushings.

Comment: @Batman It was the frequency of washing the bike. I think I may do once every two washes for the new rear derailleur. When washing, you do contaminate the grease with water. That is why I re-greased it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I throught so in the beginning, but the thread simply detached from the inner plate, and it was intact in the bolt. When you crossthread, small parts of your thread are all over the bolt/remaining thread.

Comment: @GleisonStorto - Don't use water at high pressure to do the washing. I have bikes which have lived outside for *years* and not needed this type of servicing to have perfectly good shifting.

Comment: I have never re greased a pulley bushing.  Maybe that is why I am slow and people always pass me.

Comment: @mattnz I have; but only when I stripped/soaked/scrubbed it to get the lumpy bits out and so removed all the grease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was almost certainly due to repeated removal and re-torquing. Aluminum threads on lightweight bike parts just give up the ghost sometimes in that way even when not mishandled per se.

Plastic bushing-type derailer pulleys really don't much attention in terms of lubrication. I put in a drop of lube every once in a while just to keep them quiet.

One could probably helicoil the stripped cage, but I'm obsessed with helicoiling things :).

Comment: Another fix may be to fit a bolt through the hole and put the nut on the outside of the bike.  Have to watch for binding on the chain in higher gears too.

Comment: @Criggie yeah, but I would have to recess the inner plate so it can accommodate a nut the opposite side. The tension pulley bolt is barely long enough to reach the outer part of the inner plate. It could probably be done with a press (pressing the nut into the inner plate).

Comment: I meant to replace the whole bolt with a longer one of the same diameter, and fit a nylock nut and washer out the other side.  Danger comes if the bolt's head could catch a spoke when in bottom gear, so my dirty trick is to use a bolt with a countersunk head.   Or its a replacement cage - try your local bike coop for a spare part for $cheap

Comment: I mean, helicoiling it would take 5 minutes and a $1 part if it worked.

Comment: @Criggie Accomplished, but there was no depth left to insert a washer. I will stick with the upper gears until my new derailleur arrives on Wednesday.

Comment: @GleisonStorto  also stop greasing your jockey wheels now.  They will last multiple years as-is. Once they break, its time for a whole replacement rear derailleur.

Comment: @Criggie I't use a nylock nut or jam nut on the bolt as well -- I wouldn't want it poking out anywhere it shouldn't if it worked loose.